# Only my navbar is being displayed in my react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Only my navbar is displaying and im not recieving any error. the homepage has just the navbar and a blank space

'''

```
import React from 'react';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar';
import './App.css';
import Home from './components/pages/Home';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes as Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Services from './components/pages/Services';
import Products from './components/pages/Products';
import SignUp from './components/pages/SignUp';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <Router>
        <Navbar />
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
          <Route path='/services' component={Services} />
          <Route path='/products' component={Products} />
          <Route path='/sign-up' component={SignUp} />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

'''

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For you see your navbar in other pages you can test going to localhost:3000/services and see if your navbar is there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: it is there but only the navbar is visible